# How to have unique data row from a CSV file to be used/assigned for each VU only in k6 Load Testing

Tags: javascript, load, performance-testing, load-testing, k6

My set up is this:

1. CSV File:
   -201 rows with different values/data each row.
2. Actual Load Test File:

   *201 VUs

   *Peak Load Stages:

   ```
   1m=201VUs, 
   3m=201VUs, 
   1m=0 VUs.
   ```

   *No fixed Iteration.
   *Duration is 5 minutes

My goal:

I want each VUs to have its own data row from the CSV file, that they will use for all the processes/enpoints in my default function. Then those VUs with their assigned data row will loop concurrently in any number of iteration. So in this way, any VUs will not have any same data to each other fellow VUs while looping. Because as of now, Im getting an error in some of the endpoints since some VUs are sharing same data.

1 data row from CSV = 1 VU

Example :

-Row A is to be used only for Virtual User A   --then iterate/loop using the same data (row A)

-Row B is to be used only for Virtual User B   --then iterate/loop using the same data (row B)

-Row C is to be used only for Virtual User C  --then iterate/loop using the same data (row C)

...and so forth

…each VUs iterating/looping in parallel (as how k6 VUs normally work as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Thanks for the help.